# upload master data in web-sql only once when not exist

Tags: angularjs, web-sql

I am using WEB-SQL with angularJS. The problem I am facing every time application starts it will try to upload master data of application and getting error : UNIQUE constraint failed:

I am trying to resolve this issue with the following logic but its not working also I am not sure is it best practice of doing this or not.

Please guide with best practice of handling database APIs.
Here I am checking

```
function checkTableExist(){
    var query = "SELECT * from sqlite_master where type='table' and name = 'test'",
        defer = $q.defer();
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql(query,[], function( response ){
            if(typeof(response.rows)){
                defer.resolve(false);
            }
            else{
                defer.resolve(true);    
            }

        }, function(){
            defer.resolve(false);
        });
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

when my application start I called this method to check if table exists or not.

if result is false I am creating tables and inserting data into table. if result is true I don't want to create table and insert data into this.

I am unable to achieve this.

Any support would be great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer of your question but you can remove your error : UNIQUE constraint failed: by changing your sql queries like this:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists sqlite_master();
INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO sqlite_master VALUES();
```

this way you can insert same data every time your app starts.
I hope this will help you.